# Continuously adapting neural nets with production data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, theano, keras

I have created a simple neural net (using keras) for my NLP application which classify data point into 1 of the 2 classes. 
My model gave > 95% accuracy on Test data. I have deployed the model in production. Its running good. The prediction of the model is sent as an email to users.

*These end users can send back a feedback if the prediction was right or not. I want to incorporate this feedback into the model so as continuously learn from this feedback (both positive and negative feedback) and improve *

**How can I achieve the above ?** I have read about Reinforcement Learning, Online Learning and Active Learning. 
Any pointers/tutorials (possibly with code) will be of great help.

Comment: This is just basic **incremental learning**. Nothing more, it is not reinforcment nor active learning (unless users do not decide what your model classifies). Simply add new objects which are labeled by your users to the training set and retrain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2658050/lejlot The offline training is over 3 million tweets. So cannot retrain from scratch

Comment: by retrain I mean **train incrementaly**, from the current model.